# Aligning conditions in cases environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, cases

I have a piecewise function with three "parts." I would like to have all three conditions aligned at the variable x. How do I achieve that? Here is the code I have so far:

```
\[
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
                mx^2 +nx +1, & x \le -1 \\ 
                2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, & -1 < x < 1 \\ 
                3x^2 - (m+n)x, & x \ge 1 
           \end{cases}
\]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different solution, which extends the `cases` environment. It adds an optional argument for defining array column options. The standard `cases` behavior is the default, so without optional argument it's like the normal amsmath's cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\env@cases}[1][@{}l@{\quad}l@{}]{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases}[@{}l@{\quad}r@{}l@{}]
    mx^2 +nx +1, & &x \le -1 \\
    2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, & -1 < {} &x < 1 \\
    3x^2 - (m+n)x, & &x \ge 1
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: redefined cases environment with different alignment]

Comment: Using the following generate errors with the redefinition of cases in this answer:
`\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{l}=\begin{cases}[{-0.0095} \quad {11.7464} \quad { -0.1086} \\ \qquad {-0.4413} \quad {-0.3859} \quad {-0.1111}]&\text{for }x\le 0.34\ [{-4.5403} \quad {41.5374} \quad {-64.0957}\\ \qquad {50.2411} \quad {-19.2945} \quad {2.8837}]&\text{for }x>0.34\end{cases}
\end{equation}`

Comment: @MobiusPizza Check your argument in the square brackets, it should be the syntax for `array` column definitions.

Answer (score 14):

You could use `alignedat` instead, for aligning at several places, with a big brace on the left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \left\{\begin{alignedat}{2}
    & mx^2 +nx +1, && x \le -1 \\
    & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad  & -1 < {}&x < 1 \\
    & 3x^2 - (m+n)x, && x \ge 1
  \end{alignedat}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: alignedat with brace]

Comment: Just a note - I was trying this at http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, and `alignedat` is apparently a "blocked word"; interestingly, if I replace `\begin{alignedat}{2}` with `begin{aligned}` (also for the `\end`), then it compiles in that editor, and the result looks almost the same as the image in this post. Not sure what the difference is, though... Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

this approach re-uses ideas from other answers, but in a different way:

```
\[
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
         mx^2 +nx +1, & x \le -1 \\ 
         2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n,\kern4em & \llap{$-1 < {}$} x < 1 \\ 
         3x^2 - (m+n)x, & x \ge 1 
       \end{cases}
\]
```

`\qquad` doesn't leave enough space on the second line, hence doubling it to `\kern4em`.  the `{}` after the less than sign in the `\llap` ensures the correct spacing between it and the following "x".  finally, since `\llap` puts you into horizontal mode, `$...$` are needed to restore math mode.

the result:

[image: cases example with adjusted right side]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a `\phantom{-1 <{}}` to achieve the proper spacing. This will reserve as much space as is taken up by `-1 <` (with the additional `{}` to get the proper spacing on the right hand side of the `<`):

[image]

If you also want the `1` aligned on the right hand side you can add `\phantom{-}` before the `1` to get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\Phantom}{\phantom{-1 <{}}}%
\begin{document}
\[
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
    mx^2 +nx +1,                    & \Phantom x \le           -1 \\ 
    2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, & -1     < x <   \phantom{-}1 \\ 
    3x^2 - (m+n)x,                  & \Phantom x \ge \phantom{-}1 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```