# Cases environment left alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

As I understand, cases environment is centered by default:[image] How to make it left aligned?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please refer to [THIS QUESTION][1] ; it looks like already answered. 


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/aligning-conditions-in-cases-environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to left-align the two `cases` you can use `align` for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \begin{cases}
     C=C_0+(Y-T)*\textit{MPC} \\
     Im=Im_0+\textit{MPM}*Y \\
     90+C=C_0+\textit{MPC}*\biggl(Y+\dfrac{20}{1-\textit{MPC}+\textit{MPM}}\biggr)-T \\
     10+Im=Im_0+\textit{MPM}*\biggl(Y+\dfrac{20}{1-\textit{MPC}+\textit{MPM}}\biggr)
   \end{cases} \\
& \begin{cases}
     90=Y+\dfrac{20*\textit{MPC}}{1-\textit{MPC}+\textit{MPM}} \\
     \\
     10=Y+\dfrac{20*\textit{MPC}}{1-\textit{MPC}+\textit{MPM}} \\
   \end{cases}         
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you also want to left-align all math stuff to the left margin of the page, you have to load the document class with the option `fleqn`, in this case

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
```

and add the line

```
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

in the preamble.