# Aligning more than two columns with alignedat?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, alignat

Consider this MWE, modified from [Aligning conditions in cases environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/aligning-conditions-in-cases-environment/41427#41427):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \left\{\begin{alignedat}{3}
    & mx^2 +nx +1, &\text{if } & x \le -1 \\
    & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad  &\text{if } -1 < {}&x < 1 \\
    & 3x^2 - (m+n)x, &\text{otherwise} &
  \end{alignedat}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

It results with:

[image: test.png]

I'd like to have both the `if`s and `otherwise` aligned; and the `x`s aligned.

Can that be done with `{aligned}`? If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't try this. It adds nothing to clarity and much to confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `&&` to get the conditions left aligned. To get the `x` aligned as well, in this case I would recommend using an `\hphantom`:

[image]

### Notes:

- You need to use `{-1}` for the second case so that the `-` is treated as a unary operator instead of a binary operator.

---

To answer your questions from the comments:

- Each `&` provides a `r`ight/`l`eft alignment point. That is, text *before* the `&` is right aligned and the text *after* the `&` is `l` aligned. So the first `&` aligns the `f(x) = {` to the right and the the subsequent expressions to the left. Then, the subsequent text (the beginning of the condition) is desired to be `l` aligned. That means that we need  `&&`. The first `&` would give a `r`ight alignment, -- the second `&` ensures that we have a `l`eft alignment.
- Using the `\hphantom` was an easy way to get the desired alignment. Sure it could be done with a `&` but that would have necessitated a use of a `\lap` type of macros due to the `otherwise` text. Note that the inequality expressions overlap the `otherwise` text.

Here is the results of the other two approaches:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Recommended approach: use a \verb|\hphantom{}|: 
\[
      f(x) = \left\{\begin{alignedat}{3}
        & mx^2 +nx +1,                            &&\text{if } \hphantom{-1 <{}}   x \le -1 \\
        & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad  &&\text{if } {-1} < x < 1 \\
        & 3x^2 - (m+n)x,                          &&\text{otherwise} 
      \end{alignedat}\right.
    \]
Use additional \verb|&| instead of \verb|\hphantom{}|:
\[
  f(x) = \left\{\begin{alignedat}{4}
    & mx^2 +nx +1,                            &&\text{if } &      &&  &x \le -1 \\
    & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad  &&\text{if } & {-1} &&{}< {}&x < 1 \\
    & 3x^2 - (m+n)x,                          &&\text{otherwise} 
  \end{alignedat}\right.
\]
With \verb|mathllap|:
\[
  f(x) = \left\{\begin{alignedat}{4}
    & mx^2 +nx +1,                            &&\text{if } &      &&  &x \le -1 \\
    & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad  &&\text{if } & {-1} &&{}< {}&x < 1 \\
    & 3x^2 - (m+n)x,                          &&\text{\rlap{otherwise}} 
  \end{alignedat}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, @PeterGrill - that looks freat, will accept as soon as the timer expires. Btw, why is it necessary to insert the phantom space; I'd think that ampersand `&` is enough to specify a column? And why are the double `&&` required? Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Have updated the answer to explain the double `&&` and show the complexities of just using a `&` for the alignment. Let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative would be to use the `cases` environment. It needs less ampersands here, at the cost of the `x` alignment, but I personally think it's more elegant so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    mx^2 +nx +1, &\text{if }  x \le -1 \\
    2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n,  &\text{if } -1 < x < 1 \\
    3x^2 - (m+n)x,  &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @fpast - that aligns the `if`s, but doesn't align the `x`s (I actually started with `cases`, but had this same problem of aligning the `x`s as well)

Comment: @sdaau I, too, think that this looks better...

Comment: If the x's are aligned, the final 1's are not.

Comment: This is how the display should be typeset.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \left\{\begin{alignedat}{3}
    & mx^2 +nx +1,                             &&\text{if }         &    & x \le -1 \\
    & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad   &&\text{if }         &-1< & x < 1 \\
    & 3x^2 - (m+n)x,                           &&\text{otherwise}   &&
  \end{alignedat}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

EDIT: image:

[image: test.png]

**edit** (by bbeeton): an adjusted image:

[image: output of adjusted code]

the difference here is in the spacing around the left-hand `<` sign in the second line.  this can be accomplished in either of two ways:

- `...  &-1<{} & x < 1`
- by taking advantage of the fact that the *x* is the same width in both lines, and entering them as

  ```
  & mx^2 +nx +1,                             &&\text{if }         &     x &\le -1 \\
  & 2m e^{|x|-1} + \sin \pi x - 3n, \qquad   &&\text{if }         & -1< x &< 1 \\
  ```

proper spacing around signs of operation and relation is guaranteed only if the aligning
`&` precedes the sign.

Comment: Thanks @touhami - edited your answer, and added an image; this indeed aligns both `if` and `x`, the spacing looks a bit too much ... Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau thanks, i edited my answer to correct {alignedat}{5} to {alignedat}{3}

Comment: Thanks @touhami - but that still doesn't change the large space between `if` and `-1` on the second line which could have been shorter, that's what I meant...

Comment: bad spacing after the first `<` in the second line.  that shouldn't happen with the coding shown.

Comment: Thanks, @barbarabeeton - I built the latest code as of now, and the spacing is still shown: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9G6Qe.png ; I've indicated what I mean. UPS; wait - that is actually because of the `otherwise` being too big - it seems as expected to me now...

Comment: @sdaau -- that's not what i meant -- the spaces around the less-than signs in the second line should be uniform, and they're not.  you could take advantage of the fact that the *x* in both lines at that point is always the same width, and move the & signs to (in the first line) just before the `\le`, and (in the second line) to `& < 1` and that would fix the spacing.  `&`s should always (if feasible) go *before* signs of operation or relation to ensure proper spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you can edit my answer.